# Confusion in Pumping Lemma

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, pumping-lemma

I would like to know whether we could pump $ba$ into $bbba$ where *x*=$b$,*y*=a,*z*=$\epsilon$ using the finite state machine given in the image 1.

For example as given in this image 2 where the *string* $babb$ could be pumped into $bbbabb$ using the pumping statement $b^kabb\in L(M_1),\forall k,k \ge0$ where *x*=$\epsilon$,*y*=$b$,*z*=$abb$,can we pump the string $ba$ into $bbba$ using the pumping statement $b^ka\in L(M_1),\forall k,k \ge0$ where *x*=$b$,*y*=$a$,*z*=$\epsilon$?

[image: finite automata]
[image: pumping lemma]

Answer (score 2):

To pump a string there is a minimum length on the string. This depends on the language. If a DFA is also given then the minimum length for pumping will be smaller than the number of states.

Since the DFA has 4 states in the problem that you refer to, any acceptable string of length greater than or equal to 4 can be pumped. So yes $bbba$ can be pumped.

However, which substring is going to be pumped is not your choice. In $bbba$ the substring that can be pumped is either $b$, $bb$, or $bbb$.

Suffix $ba$ cannot be said do be *pumpable* in $bbba$ because $bb(ba)^0$ is $bb$ which is not acceptable. Strangely, pumping also means pumping 0 times (which amounts to removing the substring).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36402/discussion-on-answer-by-shreesh-confusion-in-pumping-lemma).

Comment: @Justin I have joined chat.

Comment: @Shreesh:Could you help me at the [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36402/discussion-on-answer-by-shreesh-confusion-in-pumping-lemma).